# ContentObserver getting notifications about deletes, but not inserts or updates

Tags: android, contentobserver

I have the following code in my activity:

```
Cursor mCursor = managedQuery(ActivityColumns.CONTENT_URI, PROJECTION, null, null,
                getSortOrderStringFromSpinner());

        mCursor.registerContentObserver(new ContentObserver(new Handler())
        {
            @Override
            public void onChange(boolean selfChange)
            {
                ...snip...// breakpoint is set here                 
            }

            @Override
            public boolean deliverSelfNotifications()
            {
                return true;
            }
        });
```

...and in the DataProvider I am using to get my data, I am setting the notification URI in the query method to the uri of the type I am querying for:

```
c.setNotificationUri(getContext().getContentResolver(), uri);
```

Finally, in update, insert and delete, if the operation is successful, the subscribers are notified:

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(notificationUri, null);
```

The notificationUri in the line above is the URI of the item being inserted/updated or deleted.

With a breakpoint set on the "...snip..." line of code, I add, remove and update some records. I ONLY get notified about the deletes, but not updates or inserts. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was just like I suspected: the content observer was not receiving updates about inserts or updates, because the activity with the list that was supposed to be refreshed was suspended at the time. To insert or update a record in my application, user launches a different activity, where they edit the record, and they click "Submit".

The save is then performed in

```
protected void onActivityResult (int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
```

What I did not know about, and I found out when I read the documentation is that onActivityResult is:

> Called when an activity you launched exits, giving you the requestCode you started it with, the resultCode it returned, and any additional data from it. The resultCode will be RESULT_CANCELED if the activity explicitly returned that, didn't return any result, or crashed during its operation.
>
> **You will receive this call immediately before onResume() when your activity is re-starting.**

So bottom line is that the activity was not active when I performed inserts and updates, and therefore it was not getting notified about inserts or updates.

Deletes are different, because my application deletes items from a list when "Delete" is selected from the context menu. The activity remains active the whole time.

Answer (score 0):

This still needs some more testing, but it seems that the problem there was that the activity with the content observer that was not getting notified was paused when the cursor updates happened. And a paused activity does not receive events... I think...

Answer (score 0):

The call

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(notificationUri, null);
```

Should contain a reference to the content observer been notified i.e

```
getContext().getContentResolver().notifyChange(notificationUri, MyContentObserver);
```